# BEM Methology: Elements outside Block

Tags: html, css, dom, bem

Wonder if that is correct the BEM way. Let's say I have a component/block "box".

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box__title">Box Title</div>
</div>
```

This box can be used everywhere. But then for example this box can also be used in a list ex.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box__title">Box Title</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It is correct to call the DOM-Classes like that?

```
<ul class="box__list">
    <li class="box__item">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box__title">Box Title</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So "box__list" and "box__item" is somehow outside of the block "box".
"box__item" then have some specific stuff.

```
.box__item {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

It is "allowed" to do it this way or do I need here completly something different like "box-wrapper__list" and "box-wrapper__item".

Thanks for commenting. :)

Comment: If you find yourself in such a situation, I'd say you're not "seeing" the component correctly. You might be mistaken the component, the `.box` in your case, with the actual content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the elements are outside of the `.box` then no, it does not make sense to give them these classes.

You have to think what your base components/blocks (think 'building blocks') are.

A component/block is something you can (ideally) place anywhere inside your layout and still have it look/behave the same way, regardles of parent or adjacent elements. The BEM naming convention tries to enforce CSS "modularity" in this sense.

To me it looks like you definitely have a `.box` component. If you think the list should be another component/block, then name it something else, as you would name a block and not an element.

References:

[BEM key concepts](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/)

[BEM naming conventions](https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/)

Answer (score 2):

so this makes now more sense - thanks!

```
<ul class="box-wrapper">
    <li class="box-wrapper__item>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box__title">Box Title</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I completely understand the thought process behind your question and it is something I have attempted to resolve.

The solution I came up with is stopping using the `__wrap` naming convention and changing to `__inner` or `content`. Essentially a word that best describes the inside, rather than outside as wrap did.

From there we can create an example like so.

This does mean that you will have to change the way you apply classes slightly, but i did find that it helps **encapsulate** the entire **block**, rather than having to deal with the ambiguity haing `box__wrap` on the outside creates.

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='box__inner'> 
    <div class='box__head'>head</div> 
    <div class='box__main'>main</div>
    <div class='box__foot'>foot</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully my answer helps you in some way,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, #b_ element can be placed outside his block in DOM. Also different blocks & elements can intersections in DOM-tree: https://en.bem.info/forum/43/ (proof from authors of BEM-methodology).

But in your current case you shouldn't use that for positioning, your version with wrappers is correct.